# Assemblies não encontrados para Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Olá, estou trabalhando com o `Visual Studio` a pouco tempo e é a primeira vez que me deparo com essa mensagem ao tentar depurar o programa:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1126,5): error MSB3644: Os assemblies de referência para a estrutura ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" não foram encontrados.
>
> Para resolver isso, instale o SDK ou o Pacote de Direcionamento para essa versão da estrutura ou redirecione o aplicativo para uma versão da estrutura para a qual você tenha o SDK ou o Pacote de Direcionamento instalado. Observe que os assemblies serão resolvidos do GAC (Cache de Assembly Global) e serão usados no lugar dos assemblies de referência. Dessa forma, talvez seu assembly não seja direcionado corretamente para a estrutura pretendida."

Gostaria de saber o que eu precisaria fazer para poder compilar na versão que está o meu `.NET Framework` (se não me engano está na 4.7.0). Já tentei mudar o parâmetro de versão para 4.7.0 nos três arquivos .config que o programa possui, mas o compilador ainda parece referenciar a versão 4.5.

Desde já, agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Tentou referenciar automaticamente outro .NET Framework (como o v4.6) nas configurações do projeto?

Answer (score 1):

Já tive o mesmo problema.

Navegando até a pasta `bin`, você pode checar a linha 1126 do arquivo `Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets. Logo vc se depara com:

```
<!-- By default if there is no root path set then the task will assume it is Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework-->
    <GetReferenceAssemblyPaths
        Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkMoniker)' != '' and ('$(_TargetFrameworkDirectories)' == '' or '$(_FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths)' == '')"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker="$(TargetFrameworkMoniker)"
        RootPath="$(TargetFrameworkRootPath)"
        BypassFrameworkInstallChecks="$(BypassFrameworkInstallChecks)"
        >
      <Output TaskParameter="ReferenceAssemblyPaths" PropertyName="_TargetFrameworkDirectories"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths" PropertyName="_FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="TargetFrameworkMonikerDisplayName" PropertyName="TargetFrameworkMonikerDisplayName" Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkMonikerDisplayName)' == ''"/>
    </GetReferenceAssemblyPaths>
```

> Provavelmente ao tentar compilar sua aplicação, o visual studio não
>   esta encontrando as referencias para tal Assembler, Note o comentário
>   antes da tag `GetReferenceAssemblyPaths` que diz q caso ele não
>   encontre tal referencia, ele deve assumir os que estão dentro da pasta
>   `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework`. se você
>   está fazendo referencia a um Assembler que não existe logo a IDE vai
>   gerar a Exceção.

Para mudar o Estrutura de Destino do projeto você pode:

> - Click com direito sobre o projeto e selecione o `SubMenu    Propriedades`. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para usar a versão que não existe, basta efetuar o downlaod do Framework em questão?

- Pode ser direto do site [.NET SDKs for Visual Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks)

  > Ou então dentro da própria IDE:
  >
  > [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
  >   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]